# MySQL query error unknown column

Tags: mysql

why this query doesn't work, im trying to compare the field `idlic` with an existing user that belongs to that `idlic`.

the returning message from mysql is an unknown column, how do i save the value for used in a comparison.

```
select *, (select licencia from cuentas where idcuenta = ht.cuenta) as idlic
from hojastrabajo ht
where idlic = (select licencia from asociadolicencia where usuario = (select idusuario from usuarios where nombre = 'desarrollador' ))
```

Comment: where i supposed to do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in the same `select` or `where` that it is defined.  MySQL has a convenient work-around, where you can use a `having` clause instead:

```
select ht.*, (select licencia from cuentas where idcuenta = ht.cuenta) as idlic
from hojastrabajo ht
having idlic = (select licencia
                from asociadolicencia
                where usuario = (select idusuario from usuarios where nombre = 'desarrollador' )
               );
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, since you're an expert on this topic. Can this `(select licencia from cuentas where idcuenta = ht.cuenta) as idlic` be considered as bad practice, or is this perfectly normal and is just a preference?

Comment: @Alex . . . I prefer a `left join` in this case.  There are some situations where a correlated subquery has advantages, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
select ht.*, c.licencia
from hojastrabajo ht
left join cuentas c
on c.idcuenta = ht.cuenta
where c.licencia = 
    (select licencia from asociadolicencia where usuario = 
        (select idusuario from usuarios where nombre = 'desarrollador' )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use what you bring in "as idlic" in where statement. having a query as one of the select field is also not a good idea what if the (select licencia ...) returns more than one result. you need to join these tables and the put the whole conditions in where statement.